# Mocking Vue lifecycle methods

Tags: vue.js, sinon

I am writing unit tests for my vue application and i have problem because of calling session.exists function inside beforeCreate method. So how can i mock lifecycle function or vue.$session.exists. I tried to mock it using sinon, but i didn't managed to accomplish that?

Code:

```js
beforeCreate: function() {
  if (!this.$session.exists()) {
    this.$router.push('/')
  }
}
```

Error message is:

> TypeError: "cannot read property 'exists' of undefined"

Comment: Well, welcome and show us what did you try please. This way, someone can find a way out easier and faster.

Comment: You **don't** want it to call `vue.$session.exists` is that it?

Comment: beforeCreate: function () {
      if (!this.$session.exists()) {
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
    }
error message is:
TypeError: "cannot read property 'exists' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the `$session` when `mount()`ing:

```
const $session = { exists() { return true; } };
const component = mount(MyComponent, {
  mocks: {
    $session
  }
});
```

**Demo below.**

```js
var MyComponent = Vue.component('MyComponent', {
  template: '<div> Hello </div>',
  beforeCreate() { console.log('this.$session.exists() -->', this.$session.exists()); },
});

// specs code ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var mount = vueTestUtils.mount;
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it("mocks $session successfully", () => {
    const $session = { exists() { return true; } }
    const parent = mount(MyComponent, {
      mocks: {
        $session
      }
    });

    expect(parent.vm.$session).not.toBe(undefined);
  });
});

// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv()
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter())
  env.execute()
}())
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-template-compiler@2.5.15/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/2b078c68293a41d68a0a98393f497d0b0031f41a/dist/vue-test-utils.iife.js"></script>
```